# How to delete a message from a yammer group using REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, yammer

Am trying to delete a message from yammer using REST API,authentication is working properly.

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/49783214816?_method=DELETE

This is the url which am currently using,

request response details are listed below

```
response       : "" ;       
response status    : RestSharp.ResponseStatus.Completed ;  
statusCode         : System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound ;  
status Description : "Not Found" ;
```

Please help me....

If any one know the all REST API(other than https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits) please share with me....

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you do a POST with _method=DELETE instead of a GET with a querystring _method=DELETE? From the docs you linked: "DELETE requests should use querystring parameters. If your app does not support the DELETE method you can do a POST with the parameter _method=DELETE."

Comment: Now its working......use METHOD= delete with url                                                https:/​/​www.yammer.com/​api/​v1/​messages/​2413244